# How to add bookmark toolbar in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I could not find in Google or I think I don't know how to search about it.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: removed the useless pieces that were used to 'fool the auto check'

Comment: You mean Bookmark window?

Comment: http://www.skorkin.com/files/2012/05/VisualStudioTextEditorBookmarsToolbar.png

look at the image i want this toolbar in visulal studio 2012.

Answer (score 11):

i found it myself.
Click add remove buttons -> Customize ->Add tool bar -> Check text Editor check box.
problem was i didn't knew what this toolbar called.
somebody told me to enable it from view menu but in view menu text editor was already enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the toolbar area (where Start button is there) and check "Text Editor"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is late to the game, but I still have a viable copy of VS 2010 that I use sometimes.

For those who find this when searching for how to show the bookmark toolbar in Visual Studio 2010 like I did, here's how:

On the File menu, select: **View** > **Toolbars** > **Text Editor**.

That's it, easy once you know how, but difficult if you don't.